# Oracle: Dump file may be an Data Pump export dump file

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to import data from Db dump

I have created a user 'user' and Granted following permissions:

```
CONNECT RESOURCE UNLIMITED TABLESPACE DBA ALL PRIVILEGES IMP_FULL_DATABASE
```

I am running the following command:

```
imp <user>/<password>@<server> touser=<user>
FILE=C:\App\<path>\admin\orcl\dpdump\EXPDAT.DMP full=y log=imp.log;
```

While running I am getting the following error message.

```
IMP-00401: dump file "C:\App\<path>\admin\orcl\dpdump\EXPDAT.DMP" may
be an Data Pump export dump file IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

Comment: You need impdp, not imp, since your file datapump dump

Comment: I am getting issue
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation

Comment: If all you did was change the command from 'imp' to  'impdp', you would be expected to have problems.  A lot of the command-line parameters are different.  Specifically to your case, expdp does not have the 'file' or 'log' parameters.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to look at the documentation for expdp, at https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-BA74D4F6-2840-4002-A673-0A7D9CBB3D78

Answer (score 2):

There are two import and export utilities.

One is client - server based, and is also deprecated. That would be IMPORT and EXPORT, shortened as IMP and EXP.

[Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-overview.html#GUID-17FAE261-0972-4220-A2E4-44D479F519D4) is the 'new,' server based set of utilities - much more powerful and efficient at getting data in and out of your database.

You'll need to place your DMP file in a Database 'DIRECTORY' - these are known OS directories to the database, you can see them in the data dictionary via

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_DIRECTORIES
```

It's likely you already have a directory already defined just for data pump, look for something like 'DATA PUMP DIR'

Data Pump has a utility you can run from the OS, a PL/SQL API, and there is a Wizard in SQL Developer.

View > DBA menu.

Add a connection (not SYS), right-click on the Data Pump category, select Import Wizard...then walk the dialog.

We'll create and kick off the job for you, you can also watch the progress of the job and check for any errors.

[image]